# How to show only installed module's menu in drop-down list

Tags: drop-down-menu, show-hide, odoo-12, installed-applications

I made one drop-down list and now I want to show in this drop-down only which modules I have installed.

Only installed module's menus I want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you.

**Firstly for your learning:**

->Activate ***Debug*** mode.

->Then go to ***Apps***.

->***Select*** any App which you want.

->Go to ***Module Info***.

->Place your pointer at any ***field*** which are visible in front of you.

->It will give you detail of ***model*** in which all modules which are installed or not installed are placed.

**Secondly for sake of answer:**

-> installed_modules = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('state', '=', 'installed')])

->Then do whatever you want.

Comment: Hello, when i perform installed_modules field in function that time like this error are occurred.               installed_modules_id = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('state', '=', 'installed')])
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Please share your code. Secondly i want to say 'Self' only exist when you are running code inside a class method.

Comment: class HideMenus(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'
    _rec_name = 'hide_menus'

    hide_menus = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="ir.ui.menu")
    installed_modules_id = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('state', '=', 'installed')])
   
    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        res = super(HideMenus, self).write(vals)
        for rec in self:
            if u'hide_menus' in vals and rec.hide_menus:
                for est_rec in rec.hide_menus:

Comment: print("=============== Hide Menus ==============", est_rec.name)
                    print("===========   installed modules  ============", self.installed_modules_id.category_id)

Comment: You cannot use self when defining class properties.

Comment: Where you want to use installed_module_id?

Comment: installed_modules = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('state', '=', 'installed')]) use this in your write method

Comment: after for loop. actually what i want suppose i created one field in user creation form and it's name is [hide_menus] and i store all menus in it. now i select the menus from hide_menus field and compare with [installed_modules_id] if menus are will match then this menu will be hide for user.

Comment: No problem :) thanks for you given efforts behind me